# Run screen and command crontab

Tags: linux, cron, gnu-screen

I'm trying to add a new crontab that open a screen window and execute php command inside this window.

What I'm trying:

```
sudo crontab -e
10 0 * * * * screen -d -m php /var/www/script.php
```

This doesn't create a screen, but, if I remove after -m, creates normal.
This code returns that I have to run on a terminal

```
10 0 * * * * screen -d
```

How can I do this?
It's possible?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Figured out. What I had to do is send some commands to attached screen, like this:

```
screen -S sessionname -X stuff 'command'`echo -ne '\015'`
```

`echo -ne '\015'` emulates pressing the Enter key.

It was mentioned here: https://superuser.com/a/274071

Comment: Because I am very green, I didn't realize `stuff` was important to getting this to work. I thought it was example text. For any other newbies, all you  need to replace to get this to work for you is `command`. The `stuff` command is sent to screen, and the argument(s) to the stuff command are entered into the screen window, as if typed at the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked in *[How do I use crontab to start a screen session?](https://serverfault.com/questions/233084/how-do-i-use-crontab-to-start-a-screen-session)*

In cron, you do not have a terminal (see for example *[Linux: Difference between /dev/console , /dev/tty and /dev/tty0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0)*).  screen wants to run in a terminal.  Getting it to run in that situation requires special handling.

According to its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Invoking-Screen.html), the combination of `-d` and `-m` options is treated specially:

> **`-d -m`**
>
> Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
>   doesn't  attach  to  it.  This  is  useful  for  system startup
>   scripts.

In your example,

```
php /var/www/script.php
```

is a command to be run.  It may rely upon environment variables to be set to make it run properly (for instance a particular `PATH`).  The accepted answer in the other question shows how one might source the shell initialization (`.profile`) for example, to set the environment.  Your shell might use `.bash_profile`, etc., but the principle is the same.