# Shell script not running as crontab, but runs manually

Tags: java, shell, cron, raspberry-pi, minecraft

I have a script to start my Minecraft server on a Raspberry Pi 4. It has to run in a GNU screen because of my backup utility. I have already tried specifying a path and it shows up in the log as a process but it doesn't run.

I would really appreciate some help on this because my search history is so full trying to find the issue but nothing works. The Bash script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
cd /home/pi/Desktop/Servers/PvP
screen -S pvp java -Xmx2560M -Xms2560M -jar server.jar nogui
```

My crontab is as follows. I have a new line below this entry so its not that

```
00 03 * * * ./start.sh
```

I've tried specifying the full path and that doesn't work either

Edit:
I also created restart.sh which simply calls stop.sh and the calls start.sh
stop.sh is very simple

```
killall screen
```

This then calls start.sh. The entire restart.sh script is also very simple

```
./stop.sh
./start.sh
```

I put this in my crontab and started a screen session. Low and behold, at the time I set the job to start, screen terminates. I then type `screen -ls`, expecting to see the newly created window created by start.sh but it has not run. Its beyond me why this is not working. Everything works if done manually, please help this is DOING MY HEAD IN! AAAAAAH!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run screen and command crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266676/run-screen-and-command-crontab)

Comment: Where is your script located? Do you know what PWD is used for cron?

Comment: Its located in my home directory. pwd returns /home/pi

Answer (score 0):

Specify the *actual* full path, which *must* start with a slash. For example, `0 3 * * * /home/username/project/start.sh`

Comment: Ill try that but I doubt it'll work because it didn't before